# I am not able to create view in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-view

I am trying to create a view in Postgres. I am using Dbeaver to do so.
my query is as follows:

```sql
CREATE VIEW customer_master as
(
select * 
from survey_info 
  full join survey_responses on survey_info.submissionid =survey_responses.submissionid 
);
```

It's throwing an error :

> CREATE VIEW customer_master as
>   SQL Error [42701]: ERROR: column "submissionid" specified more than once.

Anyone faced such an issue?

Comment: Unrelated, but: putting the select part between parentheses is completely useless

Answer (score 4):

If you have common columns between joined table, it is required to specify all the columns required using proper aliases.

```
CREATE VIEW customer_master as
select info.submissionid as submissionid_1,
       resp.submissionid as submissionid_2, --Keep one or use 
                                            --coalesce if one is null 
                                --i.e  coalesce(info.submissionid,resp.submissionid)
       info.col2,
       info.col3,
       resp.col2,
       resp.col3
                 --other columns with aliases
 from survey_info info 
   full join survey_responses resp
  on info.submissionid =resp.submissionid
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked, Now I want to see that view that has been created using above query, I don't see anything under VIEW tab, is there any other Place Its been saved.

Comment: there was refresh issue on the DB, later it was resolved, thank you for the suggestion and help